# progress bar containing thread is not running for the second time in javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, progress-bar, task, runnable

I have a progress bar which in my application which runs properly for the first time.The progress bar runs based on the size of the observableArrayList. When I change the size of the observableArrayList and run it again or return to the page from a different page, it doesnt work properly. I am able to get only the text and the indeterminate progress bar in the page. The process count and the elapsed time are not getting displayed. I 've put the logic of this inside a Task. When I put the log lines at specific places I find that sometimes it doesnt enter certain places like Platform.runlater(new Runnable) inside the task's call method. Please find the code below. I am using scenebuilder for the UI part.

```
public class ProgressBarController implements Initializable {

public static final Stage stage ;
@FXML
ProgressBar progressBar;
@FXML
public static Button cancelButton;
@FXML
Button save;
@FXML
Label totalprocess;
@FXML
Label runningprocess;



/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    final Task task;
    task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            for (int i = 0; i < rightObservableArrayList.size(); i++) {

                final int k = i + 1;
                //setting the value for total number of processes
                totalprocess.setText("total number of process");
                //setting the value for the current process. It gets updated as the loop increments.
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runningprocess.setText(Integer.toString(k));
                    }
                });

                /*
                  some processing for the current val 
                */

                //update the progressBar
                updateProgress(i + 1, <totalprocesssize>);
                updateMessage(String.valueOf(i));
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        /*
                         some code to display the total time to run the process
                        */
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    Label labelCount = new Label();
    labelCount.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {

              ///some code
            }
        }
    });
}
@FXML
    public void cancelFired(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        cancelFlag = true;
        progress.setScene(cancelButton.getScene());
        progress.close();
    }
```

Any ideas about why this happens will be really helpful. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Are you running the same task instance twice, or creating a new one?

Comment: I have updated my code with the cancelFired method which gets fired when I click on the cancelButton from the UI. When I click on the cancelButton the cancelFlag which is static is set to true and a for loop which is inside the task checks for this flag's true status and breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaFX Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

> As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused.
>   See [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) for a reusable Worker.